# Why does a suffix tree have a linear number of nodes (relative to input string size)?

Tags: data-structures, trees, strings, suffix-trees

Aren't there $n^2$ unique substrings of a string (irrespective of the alphabet size)? Perhaps the number of unique *suffix substrings* is less than the number of unique *substrings* of a string.

Comment: Have you read some articles/papers/tutorials explaining how suffix trees can be constructed in linear time with linear space complexity?

Comment: I have a very rough idea of McCreight's suffix tree construction algorithm.

Comment: They may be $\approx n^2$ many substrings, but suffix strings only store *suffices*, which there are only linearly many of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a text of length $n$ we have up to $1+{ n+1 \choose 2}$ different substrings, however there are only $n+1$ suffixes (for every suffix you can pick the position where it starts).

I assume you consider the compressed suffix tree (edge labels are words). This is a tree with $n+1$ leaves and every internal node has at least two children. Thus we have less interior nodes than leaves an therefore the tree has size $O(n)$.

Notice that in the uncompressed version (edge labels a characters) with a large alphabet, you can have super-linear suffix trees. For example, consider the text `abcdefghijk...`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. is n choose 2 (i.e., the max number of unique substrings in a string) order of n^2?

Comment: Yes it is ${n \choose 2}=n(n-1)/2=\Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: @A.Schulz I think there is a small mistake in the number of unique substrings. It should be $1 + {{n+1} \choose 2}$. ${n \choose 2}$ does not take into account single alphabet substrings.

Comment: @Paresh How are you getting $1+\binom{n+1}{2}$?
On [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) it is given as $\binom{n+1}{2}$.

Comment: How is it guaranteed that the internal nodes will have at least 2 children? As per my understanding, number of children depends on the number of suffixes that start from that node. How did you count the children for the internal nodes?

Comment: @clytondantis: in the **compressed** suffix tree you have at least 2 children per node, otherwise this node will be contracted